# Spring AbstractMongoEventListener does not trigger

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, event-listener, dbref

Context: Java8 application, Spring MongoDB 1.9.1

I've got a collection containing entities of A, and another collection containing entities of B. In my domain model, Entity A has a collection of B as DBRef like this

```
class A {
    @DBRef
    List<B> myBs;
}
```

Moreover, I have registered two AbstractMongoEventListeners, one for A and another one for B. If I fetch a document of type A or B directly via MongoTemplate.findById(), the onAfterConvert() method is triggered alright. However, if I just fetch A, I'd expect that the onAfterConvert method is triggered also for each item B in the DBRef'ed list of A. Actually, it is not.

I hazard a guess that this works as designed, on the other side I don't the see the reason why onAfterConvert shouldn't work for any entity/document being loaded from the DB.

Long story short, I need to do some post processing for all items of B after A has been loaded. Does anyone have an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue, if there are better ways to solve this, but this works for me:

Overwrite the resolveDbRef() method in an extended DefaultDbRefResolver and pass it your own MappingMongoConverter when creating the bean.

Other answers/recommendations welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1044 - should be fixed in next major Spring Data MongoDB release (1.10).

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @Sid I could not post a comment.

Comment: @Joe Taras: further information is in the linked issue - I just found it in the Spring Data MongoDB Jira (as I had a similar problem) and thought it might be useful to know that it is being fixed (in fact working in the Ingalls M1 version).